# Не могу запустить программу на java

Tags: java, компиляция

[image: Версия Java 9.0.1, вроде все верно указано]

Не могу понять в чем проблема, не дает запустить программу

Comment: Рядом там где Вы пытаетесь запустить есть стрелочка направленная вниз. Нажмите на неё и потом "Edit configuration". Потом нажмите на зеленый плюсик, из списка выберите Application. в поле Main class выберите ваш main класс

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблема решена)